# I have a main of a game, and i'm trying to get to the method .go()

Tags: c++, class, program-entry-point

but, while doing that the VS compiler shouts that `expression must have class type`, although in the line above i made an instance of that class, now im working on this project from Stack, and not heap so I don't wish to use `new`, as i would have to delete that instance afterwards... any advice? 
this is what i tried doing,

```
 #include"Game.h"
 #include <iostream>

 int main()
    {
     Game g();
     g.go();
     return 0;
    }
```

Comment: `Game g;` - drop the _parentheses_. `Game g();` declares a function called `g` which returns a `Game`.

Comment: i can't the constructor creates many objects needed for the game

Comment: The constructor will still be called.

Comment: `Game g;` calls the constructor. `Game g();` declares a function.

Comment: Google for "most vexing parse" to see other similar yet more complex examples.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As mentioned in the comments, you need to change `Game g();` to `Game g;`. You only use parentheses when you have values to pass in for the constructor. For example, if your constructor was:

```
 Game(std::string player, int damage);
```

Then your code should be:

```
Game g("MyGuy", 22);
```

However, when you just do `Game g();` the compiler reads it like you're trying to declare a function -- which you're, of course, not.

Comment: "the compiler reads it like you're trying to call a function " - no, it thinks you are trying to _declare_ a function.

Comment: Ah, my apologies; I'll fix my answer right away. Thank you.